# error: package javax.mail does not exist

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I want to run a java program to send emails but I am getting the following errors:

```
SSLEmail.java:4: error: package javax.mail does not exist
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
             ^
SSLEmail.java:5: error: package javax.mail does not exist
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
             ^
SSLEmail.java:6: error: package javax.mail does not exist
import javax.mail.Session;
             ^
```

I downloaded the javax.mail package and changed the path in environment variables,but still getting the same error..

Someone kindly help where I might be wrong with . thanks in advance for any help..

Comment: Did you include information about location of this package in in your classpath?

Comment: You didn't include that jar in your build path, check your project options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you miss `javax.mail.jar` in your classpath. Download and add it.

```
javac -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\javamail-1.4.7\mail.jar" SSLEmail.java
```

Comment: @Pragya not possible. Show how you compile your class.

Comment: following is how I compiled   :      C:\>cd 6sem

  C:\6sem>set path=%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\Program F
iles (x86)\Java\jre7\javamail-1.4.7\mail.jar

C:\6sem>javac SSLEmail.java
SSLEmail.java:4: error: package javax.mail does not exist
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
                 ^
SSLEmail.java:5: error: package javax.mail does not exist
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
                 ^
SSLEmail.java:6: error: package javax.mail does not exist
import javax.mail.Session;
                 ^

Comment: You do not need to add it to your `path`. You have to add it to your `classath`. See my edited answer

Comment: did you mean the entire line  higligted needs to be written in the classpath .

Comment: @Pragya YES or you define a variable classpath wehre you add all your jars and write only `javac -cp %CLASSPATH% SSLEmail.java`

Comment: Have you double qoutes arround the path? or you need to escape the blank in the path.

Comment: thanks it worked...but sorry I can't upvote you as it requires 15 reputation....   but really thanks for helping me out of this trouble..